# Ext.ux.form is undefined

Tags: extjs

I'm creating a UI base on SCRUD. My problem is that I'm having a problem on creating a searchField, it goes an error always saying Ext.ux.form is undefined.

Could someone help me regarding this problem?

This is what I've tried so far:

```
Ext.ns('Region');
Region.app = function() {
return{
    init: function() {
        Ext.QuickTips.init();
        Ext.form.Field.prototype.msgTarget = 'side';

        Region.app.AddEditRegion = function(){


        };

        Region.app.store = new Ext.data.JsonStore({
            proxy: new Ext.data.HttpProxy({
                url: "<?php echo url_for('/contract_system/index.php/regions')?>",
                method: "POST"
            }),
            reader: new Ext.data.JsonReader({
                root: "data",
                id: "id",
                totalProperty: "totalCount",
                fields: [

                    {name: "id", mapping: "id" },
                    {name: "description", mapping: "description" }
                ],
            }),
            //data: {data:{id: 1, description: 'test'}},
            baseParams: {limit: 20},
            remoteSort: false,
            autoLoad: true
        });


        var addItem = new Ext.Action ({
            text: 'Add',
            // icon: 'images/add1.ico',
            width: 60,
            //disabled: true,


        });
        var editItem = new Ext.Action ({
            text: 'Edit',
            // icon: 'images/edit.ico',
            width: 60,
            disabled: true,


        });

        var deleteItem = new Ext.Action ({
            text: 'Delete',
            // icon: 'images/delete1.ico',
            width: 60,
            disabled: true,


        });         
                       //           

         // var searchField = new Ext.app.SearchField({store: store});

        Region.app.empGrid = new Ext.grid.GridPanel({

            viewConfig: {
                forceFit: true,
                autoFill: true,
                stripeRows: true

                       // 
        },

            listeners: {

                rowdblclick : Region.app.AddEditRegion,
                rowcontextmenu: function(grid, rowIndex, e) {
                       e.stopEvent();
                       grid.getSelectionModel().selectRow(rowIndex);
                       menu_grid.showAt(e.getXY());                       
                       return false;
                    }
            },

            renderTo: 'region',
            sm: new Ext.grid.RowSelectionModel({singleSelect: true}),
            border: false,
            loadMask: true,
            frame: false,
            title: 'Regions',
            height: 525,
            anchor: '100%',
            store: Region.app.store,
            columns: [
                new Ext.grid.RowNumberer(),
                {
                    header: 'ID', 
                    width: 10, 
                    sortable: true,
                    locked: true,
                    hidden: false,
                    dataIndex: 'id' 
                },{
                    header: 'Description', 
                    width: 50, 
                    sortable: true,
                    locked: true,
                    dataIndex: 'description' 
                }
                ],

            tbar: [
                'Search : ',
                    new Ext.ux.form.SearchField({
                        store: Region.app.store,
                        width: 200
                    }),'->',{

                        xtype: 'toolbar',
                        items: [
                            addItem, editItem, deleteItem
                        ]
                        }
                ],   

            bbar: new Ext.PagingToolbar({
                pageSize: 20,
                store: Region.app.store,
                displayInfo: true,
                // plugins: new Ext.ux.ProgressBarPager() 
            })


        });


    }

}



}();
Ext.onReady(Region.app.init, Region.app);
```

Comment: what version of extjs is this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Ext.ux.form.SearchField is a user extension and is not included in the extjs library out of the box. You need to include the file with this class in your page.

Comment: do I need to call the class to the page?